# how to make my nav bar mobile responsive to drop down

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have this as my navigation bar and i would like it to be responsive on mobile devices so that on small screens it becomes a drop down menu. Something like this.

MENU
HOME
+PORFOLIO
-WEDDING
-LOVE
ABOUT
+BLOG
-STORIES
-ARCHIVE
CONTACT

any help would be great as i am having no luck figuring this out on my own...

```css
img{
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 
}

/*navbar*/

#wrap{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-right: 48px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 50px;
 
}

.navbar li a{
 display: block;
}

.navbar li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: left;
 
}

.navbar a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #9c9c9c;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px;
 background-color: white;
}

.navbar li ul{
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 
}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover{
 color: black;
}

.navbar li:hover ul{
 display: block;
} 

.navbar li ul li{
 display: block;
}

p{
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-decoration: none;

}


footer{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Lora" serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Instagram</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Instagram.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
 
a p:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
  
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
             
             <img src="Images/NewLogoBlack.png" class="img-responsive" width="250px" height="250px">
         
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
         
                 
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
             
             

   <div id="wrap">
   <ul class="navbar">
 
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li> 
   <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="wedding.html">WEDDING</a></li>
      <li><a href="Love.html">LOVE</a></li>
      
   </ul>         
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html">US</a></li>
   </ul>         
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="NewBlogPage3.html">STORIES</a></li>
     <li><a href="Archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>      
   <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>   
   </div>   

       
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><footer>All images Copyright © Seaward Photography 2016. Based in San Diego, California. Available for destinations worldwide.</footer></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            
           
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried bootstrap but can't figure it out @n1c9

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make it work for you. I've deleted your own nav bar and css, and added a bootstrap 3 responsive nav bar. In a custom css, I included your own style + some tweaks to the navbar of bootstrap. In the html file I also added bootstrap css & js and Jquery with a CDN.

HTML

```
 <html>
 <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bootstrap 3 - Hamburger menu</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Instagram.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">

    a p:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    </style>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                <img src="Images/NewLogoBlack.png" class="img-responsive" width="250px" height="250px">

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">



<div id="wrap">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PORTFOLIO<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Wedding.html">WEDDING</a></li>
            <li><a href="Love.html">LOVE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="AboutUs.html">US</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">BLOG<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="NewBlogPage3.html">STORIES</a></li>
             <li><a href="Archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</div>          

</div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><footer>All images Copyright © Seaward Photography 2016. Based in San Diego, California. Available for destinations worldwide.</footer></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>


        </div>
    </div>




<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

#wrap{
    font-family: "Lora" serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-right: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 50px;

}

p{
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: "Lora" serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-decoration: none;

}


footer{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lora" serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;

}

/* BOOTSTRAP TWEAKS */

.navbar-default {
background: none;
border: none;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #9c9c9c;
}

.caret {
    border-top-color: #9c9c9c;
border-bottom-color: #9c9c9c;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  }

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline #9c9c9c;
    background: none; 
    }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    background: none;
    }

.dropdown-menu {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```